# What's needed to set up a personal solar power system?

Tags: solar-power

I'd like to set up a solar power system to power a small house, say 20 kWh per day, 600 kWh per month.

What equipment do I need to make it happen?  Production and storage are both important.  I'm looking for a full shopping list and ways of estimating the sizing that I'll need.

Comment: how much power you consume per day?

Comment: It's on the low side - probably 20 KwH per day.  600 a month.

Comment: Where in the world are you? And are you connected to the electricity grid? Do you want self-sufficiency on average over the year (i.e. grid exports are at least as big as grid imports), or every day of the year?

Comment: Located in Israel, and looking to detach from the grid completely.

Comment: Also useful - http://euanmearns.com/how-much-battery-storage-does-a-solar-pv-system-need/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

For estimating the solar power system requirement it depends on mainly following factor

1. Your power consumption.
2. Sun light peak value.
3. Your power storing device.
4. How much energy can a Solar panel generate over a period of time?

there are many walls solar panel is available lets take one example

The power generation rating of a Solar panel is also given in Watts (eg STP010, 10W). To calculate the energy it can supply to the battery, multiply Watts by the hours exposed to sunshine, then multiply the result by 0.85 (this factor allows for natural system losses).

For the Solar 100W panel in 4 hours* of sunshine, `100 x 4 x 0.85 = 340WH`. This is the amount of energy the Solar panel can supply to the battery.

```
As your requirement is 600000 so per day is 20000
```

So according to your requirement 20 kwh per day so you need `20000/340=59` panel

and for easy calculation i found one site [Calculate Estimate of solar power system](http://www.affordable-solar.com/residential-solar-home/Residential-Calculator)

Here is a list of the PV system basics:

```
 1. Panels

 2. Mounting equipment 

 3. DC-to-AC inverters

 4. Tracking mounts

 5. Disconnect switches

 6. Wiring and fuse box connections

7. Utility power meters
```

For more information you should contacts to solar system service provider.

**Storage device**

As your electical power usually needs to be available when the sun is not shining, it usually neccessary to store electricity.
Now a days there are many types of batteries and generator are available which stores the electricity produced by solar panel.
The normal storage is the Lead-Acid battery.

[image]

for more details [follow the link](http://www.freesunpower.com/batteries.php)

Comment: 10 **peak** hours of sun in a month? That's incredibly low. Have you mistakenly compared daily production with monthly demand? But then, 10 **peak** hours of sun in a day would be way too high: somewhere in the range 3-6 is much more likely.

Comment: The only issue with this setup (and it won't be an issue for everyone) is that it doesn't allow the solar panels to power the house if the grid connection fails due to safety concerns for maintenance workers. It is possible to use a setup similar to the wiring for an emergency generator, but that usually involves the addition of expensive batteries.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers i just given the example let me modify it

Comment: You're still comparing **daily** sun with **monthly** demand. And tracking mounts are by no means a systems basic: most PV systems don't have them, because they're simply not worth the additional maintenance.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers thanks for finding fault , oh i got it i just misunderstand i modified it, is that ok now?

Comment: This helps with the generation aspect - what about the storage aspect?

Comment: Very good answer.  Regarding the schematic that you posted - where does the battery go in this picture?  Can I just eliminate the line to the utility meter & grid?

Comment: for that you should concern the solar panel service that make you understand better :)

Comment: @Laizer Yes, you can eliminate the grid connection, but in that case you will need enough storage to power your home during cloudy weather. Even with batteries you may still run out of electricity during long periods without good sunlight.

Comment: The batteries connect to the inverter, if it's hybrid solar inverter. The another option is to add a battery charger (with batteries connected to it) in between PV and inverter.

Comment: TKS so muvh...supremely useful info

Answer (score 4):

*I'm answering only the estimating part of your question, the other answers cover the rest of the question satisfactorily.*

I estimated your future system by your requirements in [African PV GIS](http://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvgis/apps4/pvest.php?map=africa&lang=en) for Haifa (you can elaborate more for yourself).
You'll need at least **PV grid of 7kW<sub>p</sub>**. The area of the PV grid would be approx. 40 m<sup>2</sup>.
The optimized setup would be inclination=28°, orientation=-15° (15° from South towards East). The yearly approx. total energy production would be 11100 kWh with a daily average of 30.4 kWh. The critical month is December with only average 19.00 kWh per day.

This catch can be partly avoided by raising the PV inclination to let's say 45° (orientation=-15°). The total energy production would then be 4% lower, but average daily production in December would be 20.70 kWh (9% more).

To backup your system from [batteries for 3 days](http://www.civicsolar.com/battery-sizing-tool) would mean at least 60 kWh of storage capacity. It would mean **at least 1500 Ah of <strike>12 V</strike> 48 V batteries**. Not to damage the batteries too quickly one usually doubles the storage capacity (3000 Ah of 48 V batteries).

There is an important remark on this:
To disconnect this relatively big energy demand (20 kWh a day) from grid will be rather expensive. You should try to optimize your energy consumption as mentioned in many answers on this site. If your consumption was a maximum estimate, the number would be lower.